# Any help with this phrase?

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage

> ジョンさんは日本語を**上手に**話します。

The thing is that I don't understand why 上手 has the particle に.
I'm reviewing an examination sheet, and this is the answer to one of the questions.
The only possible thing that I can come off with is that the particle NI is there to simply emphasize that John is good at speaking IN Japanese, although I don't usually see 上手 paired with に. I usually see it with が.

Thanks beforehand :D

Comment: I feel like this should be a duplicate, but I couldn't find a good target.

Comment: `I usually see it with が` -- が, not だ ?

Answer (score 2):

上手 is ordinarily a [形容動詞]{けいようどうし} or "na-adjective". It could be used as a noun on its own, but more commonly it's describing something else.

Like with other 形容動詞, it takes な when describing another noun attributively - just as it would be followed by だ・です to describe something predicatively (like 「彼は日本語（が）上手です」). But here, it is describing a *verb* (話します, i.e. the formal form of 話す) attributively, so it takes に.

This is common grammar; you may also be familiar with [静]{しず}かに "quietly", or at least [本当]{ほんとう}に "truly", which is practically a set expression by itself. This に is essentially the "-ly" part (disregarding of course that in English we say "well" rather than "goodly").

Using が here would make no sense; it would have to mean something like "As for John, his skill speaks Japanese". (Or his [flattery](https://jisho.org/search/%E4%B8%8A%E6%89%8B), using an alternate definition.)

Comment: Nitpick:  本当に means "really"/"truly", not "honestly"; that would be 正直に.

Comment: @istrasci I'm not entirely sure I could adequately explain the distinction in English, and I've been speaking it since infancy (40+ years now). But I agree that dictionaries will consistently gloss the two words that way, so I edited that part. (Also noteworthy: English *does* have a word "goodly" - but it's also an adjective, and the meaning is not clearly related to "good".)

Answer (score 0):

上手 paired with が? There are some uses as a noun, but generally, as here, it is a keiyoudōshi used adverbially.